# One outlet on 2 circuits

Tags: electrical

In preparing to move an electrical outlet I plugged an appliance into the receptacle and then flipped circuit breakers on and off until the appliance went quiet.  I then went to work but as a precaution I double-checked things with a voltage tester and was surprised to find the black wire was still hot.  I then flipped an adjacent breaker and the hot black went dead.  My conclusion is that during recent renos this one outlet was somehow wired into 2 different circuits.  Obviously this presents a risk of accidental electrocution but is it otherwise dangerous?

Comment: I’ve had this happen on multiwire branch circuits when disconnecting only one leg. The disconnected leg still light up a non contact voltage tester, perhaps because of some coupling of the still-live conductor into the dead one. 

Are you familiar with the concept of multiwire branch circuits?

Comment: No, I know nothing of multiwire branch circuits

Comment: In North America you would absolutely expect to find this kind of wiring in kitchens prior to around 2003. If you look closely at the two hot (gold colour) screws on the side of the outlet, there should be a missing metal tab. This means that the two outlets on the receptacle don’t share a hot wire. It’s called a split receptacle.

Comment: Is this a standard "duplex" receptacle, i.e., two receptacles in one unit? Is one breaker connected to one receptacle and the other breaker connected to the other receptacle? Or must both breakers be off for power to be off on one of the two receptacles?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities. One is that you have things seriously messed up. The other is a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit or MWBC.

An MWBC uses 2 hot wires from opposite legs/phases, plus a shared neutral wire. This can provide twice the power with only 50% more wire (excluding ground, which can be handled in multiple ways) than a single 120V circuit. It also allows for a circuit that includes both 240V and 120V receptacles, which can be handy in certain kitchen (European appliances) or workshop situations.

One of the neat tricks to do with an MWBC is to remove the tab on the hot side of a duplex receptacle and use the top with one hot wire and the bottom with the other hot wire. That allows you to, for example, plug in a toaster and a griddle at the same time without overloading the circuit, since each receptacle can use a full 15A or 20A instead of having to share. If your original receptacle is a duplex receptacle and the tab is removed on the hot side (should still be present on the neutral side) then you have an MWBC.

However, there is a catch. MWBCs are now required to have *common shutoff*. That can done using a double-breaker or a handle tie. Both of those solutions (a) make it so that if you turn off 1/2 the circuit you will always turn off the entire circuit and (b) force the two hots to come from adjacent spaces on the panel which guarantees (well, close to guarantees...) that they will be on opposite legs. If they are not connected then someone might unknowingly move things around with the result that the two halves are on the *same* leg which will prevent 240V receptacles from working (but most people don't have any 240V receptacles on an MWBC) and also risks overloading the neutral, which is a *big* problem.

So check if that tab is missing. Also check to make sure you have 240V between the two hots. If both of those are true then you should rearrange things so that you have a proper side-by-side-breaker MWBC and add a handle tie or swap for a double-breaker. If either of those is *not* true then come back here with more details...you'll have some work to do.